# dynamic active for particular page with same name but different queries in php

Tags: php

I have many pages with same name but different queries 
`browse.php?type=student`
`browse.php?type=faculty`
`browse.php?type=employee`
`browse.php?type=gaurdian`

In nav bar under student menu i have sub-menu browse with link `browse.php?type=student`,
under faculty menu i have sub-menu with link `browse.php?type=faculty`
now the problem is when I active link using

```
<?=($pg=='browse')?'active':'';?>
```

Then all `browse.php` links are getting activated . how can i active browse sub-menu under student menu when i pass `browse.php?type=student` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will help you to do what you want

```php
<?=($pg == 'browse' && $_GET['type'] == 'student') ? 'active':'';?>
```

I just get the `type` from the url and then check it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've understood well, but you can use a variable for the type (student or faculty or employee...) and use it for css:

```
<?php
$type = $_GET['type'];
?>
...
<?=($pg=='browse' && $type=='student')?'active':'';?>
```